# I'm wondering definition of "E is a splitting over F"

Tags: extension-field

I know the definition of splitting field $E$ for $f(x)\in F[x]$
but I am confused by this definition: $E$ is a spliiting over $F$ (not $f(x)$).

I want to know that... please answer!

Comment: In my phone, mathematical symbol is not supported ;( I'm sorry this point.

Answer (score 2):

> **Definition:** Let $F$ be a field with algebraic closure $\bar{F}$. Let $$A=\{f_i(x)\mid i\in I\}$$ be a collection of polynomial in $F[x]$. A field $E\leq\bar{F}$ is the **splitting field of** $A$ **over** $F$ if $E$ is the smallest subfield of $\bar{F}$ containing $F$ and all the zeroes in $\bar{F}$ of each of the $f_i(x)$ for $i\in I$. A field $K\leq\bar{F}$ is called an **splitting field over** $F$ if it is the splitting field of some set of polynomials in $F[x]$

Comment: Thanks :) now I have no books inevitably...;( ...... ummm then i think R is not a splitting field over Q and C is a splitting field over R, is it correct?

Comment: @hobin: see this link http://math.stackexchange.com/q/127110/8581

Comment: Thanks!! I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Yes, thanks, good help! +

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for your kind words. I mean all of them. Thanks for your actions to me, Amy. :-)